# Exoplayer not looping the video

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using Exoplayer in my android app to play video and audio files. according to [Exoplayer developer's guide,](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html)in order to loop a video/audio, this is what you have to do

```
MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri, ...);
// Loops the video indefinitely.
LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
```

So I implemented it like this in my Activity's onCreate method

```
    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(factory);

    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,trackSelector);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    bandwidthMeter2 = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
      Util.getUserAgent(this, applicationName), bandwidthMeter2);

// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
    extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
    mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri,dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

    loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
```

But looping of my video file is not taking place. it just plays once.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I discovered that there was some crucial info left out in Exoplayer developers guide. after creating `LoopingMediaSource` instance, one should not call `simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);` but instead call `simpleExoPlayer.prepare(loopingSource);`. below is the complete code

```
     BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelection.Factory factory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(factory);

    simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this,trackSelector);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

    // Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
    bandwidthMeter2 = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

// Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
      Util.getUserAgent(this, applicationName), bandwidthMeter2);

// Produces Extractor instances for parsing the media data.
    extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();

        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoUri,dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);
    // Loops the video indefinitely.
    LoopingMediaSource loopingSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource);

    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(loopingSource);
```

Answer (score 29):

## Simplest solution yet

just use  `player.setRepeatMode(player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);`

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand why it addresses the problem. That often reduces the amount of follow-up questions, and can really help new developers understand the underlying concepts. That's especially important here, where there's already four other answers; it's worth calling out what sets your approach apart from the existing answers. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Comment: sorry @JeremyCaney from now on i'll explain the code also .

Comment: `player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE` should be called on the type `ExoPlayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE`

Answer (score 8):

You can simply set repeat mode as "Repeat_MODE_ONE".

Example for **Kotlin**:

```
  val player: SimpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
        context,
        DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
        DefaultTrackSelector(),
        DefaultLoadControl()
    ).apply {


       repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE

    }
```

p.s.The player is from com.google.android.exoplayer2

Answer (score 3):

```
player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
```

The above line of code instantiates the ExoPlayer with the default track selector. We can avoid creating bandwidth meter, track selector if we are not customising the track selector.

Looping can be achieved using LoopingMediaSource. We have to pass the loop count in the LoopingMediaSouce constructor. If we want to loop the media indefinitely, it is better to use `setRepeatMode()` method of the player.

```
new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource, 3)
```

Attaching a sample for reference.

```
<code>
    private MediaSource getLoopingMediaSource() {
        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(ExoPlayerActivity.this, Util.getUserAgent(ExoPlayerActivity.this, "application-name"));
        MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Samples.MP4_URI);
        LoopingMediaSource loopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mediaSource, 3);
        return  loopingMediaSource;
        }

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    playerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.prepare(getLoopingMediaSource());
    player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

the only solution that worked for me was this:

```
    simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
    exoPlayer.requestFocus();
    simpleExoPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            switch (playbackState) {
                case Player.STATE_READY:
                    prog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                    prog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    simpleExoPlayer.seekTo(0);
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_IDLE:
                    simpleExoPlayer.retry();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you as I need to handle the Ended event, it is possible to do it like this:

```
    player.addListener(object : Player.Listener {
    override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
        if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED) {
            ...
            player.seekTo(0)
            player.play()
        }
    }
})
```